# Why isn't the Iptables persistent service saving my changes?

Tags: iptables, iptables-persistent

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-ip-tables-on-ubuntu-12-04) tutorial to set up IP rules on ubuntu 12.04. Everything worked fine on setup -- but now I've made changes to the firewall that do not persist upon reboot. I do not understand why that is. Here is a demonstration of how I am using iptables-persistent. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ sudo service iptables-persistent start
 * Loading iptables rules...                                                                                             *  IPv4...                                                                                                              *  IPv6...   

$ sudo iptables -L   //shows a certain rule
$ iptables -D INPUT ... //command successfully drops the rule
$ sudo iptables -L   //shows rule has been deleted

 $ sudo service iptables-persistent restart
 * Loading iptables rules...                                                                                             *  IPv4...                                                                                                              *  IPv6...                                                                                                      [ OK ] 
 $ sudo iptables -L  //rule is back
```

Comment: I'm noticing the `iptables -D INPUT` rule isn't in `sudo` are you sure it's actually reporting a success? Does the behavior change if you do run it within `sudo`?

Comment: Curse whoever's idea is was to make `sudo iptables-save` NOT permanently save iptables configurations.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`iptables-persistent` does not work that way. Restarting the `iptables-persistent` "service" does not capture the current state of the iptables and save it; all it does is reinstate the iptables rules that were saved when the package was last configured.

To configure `iptables-persistent`, you need to tell it about your current iptables ruleset.

One way to accomplish that is as follows:

```
iptables-save >/etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-save >/etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

Or, equivalently, the `iptables-persistent` package also provides the following:

```
dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
```

(You will need to answer yes to the questions about whether to save the rules.)

After that, the next time `iptables-persistent` is started/restarted, the iptables rulesets you expect will be loaded.

Comment: make sure you don't have anything like `firewall-cmd` which would block `iptables-persistent` changes and load its own rules ahead

Comment: PLEASE README!  As @lvan Avdonin said above. YOU MUST DISABLE firewalld, or it will load its own iptables rules, and will override your own /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Answer (score 16):

Very simple way to save the current iptables rules is to use the command:

`sudo service netfilter-persistent save`

Using the above, which works at least in Ubuntu after installing the `netfilter-persistent` (and `iptables-persistent`) package, there is no need to run manually the iptables commands or to reconfigure the package (as suggested by even the accepted Answer above).

Comment: Is it `sudo service netfilter-persistent save` or `sudo service netfilter-persistent save .` ? (Dot at the end.)

Comment: Thanks for noting that, the correct command is w/o the dot at the end of line. Corrected the Answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much There is nothing about `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` or `v6` on my system before install `iptables-persistent`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ iptables ... DROP //command successfully drops the rule
$ sudo iptables -L   //shows rule has been deleted
```

That's not what `DROP` means or does.  From `man iptables`:

> ...the special values ACCEPT, **DROP,** QUEUE or RETURN. ACCEPT means to let the packet through.  DROP means *to drop the packet on the floor.*  QUEUE means...

So what you've done is add a new rule.  It may effectively supersede any number of other rules, but those rules still exist.

When checking stuff like this (your `iptables -L` output), I would feed it though `grep "string unique to this rule"` rather than use your eyes.  It's easier and faster to do, and less error prone.

```
iptables -L | grep "some unique string"
```

If you want to delete a rule, use the `-D` switch; the man page describes two forms of this:

> -D, --delete chain rule-specification
>
> -D, --delete chain rulenum
>
> Delete one or more rules from the selected chain.  There are two versions of this command: the rule can be specified as a number in the chain (starting at 1 for the first rule) or a rule to match.

Comment: sorry that was unclear. I am using the -D option to DROP a rule. See the change above

Comment: `-D` stands for "delete" not "DROP" Using the term "DROP" to mean anything other than a jump target when talking about `iptables` is confusing as hell.

Answer (score 4):

As explained by [@steven-monday](/users/4604/steven-monday), you can save your rule set by yourself in the proper directory (namely: `/etc/iptables/rules.v{4,6}`).

However, [@OpenITeX](/users/191834/openitex) is right: calling the `save` action of `service netfilter-persistent` is better.

As of today (in 18.10), iptables-save is builtin, but `iptables-persistent` is **not** installed. Hence, the plugin directory called by `service netfilter-persistent` is empty, and service prints out that the ruleset was saved, whereas it was not.

TLDR: install `iptables-persistent` and check that the plugin directory `/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d` contains plugins.

---

Here is how I figured that out:

```
$ cat /etc/init.d/netfilter-persistent 
...
case "$1" in
...
save)
    log_action_begin_msg "Saving netfilter rules"
    /usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent save
    log_action_end_msg $?
    ;;
```

Then check the `/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent` script, notice it invokes external scripts:

```
$ cat /usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent
...
PLUGINS=/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d
...
run_plugins () {
    if [ -d ${PLUGINS} ]; then
        run-parts -v -a ${1} ${PLUGINS}
    fi
}

case $1 in
start|save|flush)
    run_plugins ${1}
    ;;
```

Then I noticed that `/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d` was empty.

Comment: yes, @OpenITeX is right. The directory(`/etc/iptables`) doesn't exists before `sudo apt install iptables-persistent`. And then `sudo netfilter-persistent save` is effective.