# cannot get iptables to auto load rules on reboot with iptables-persistent

Tags: debian, iptables, reboot, iptables-persistent

I need some help, or advice.

I have a latest server I am trying to get into production and I cannot get it to load its rules on a reboot.

"Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)" it is up to date in its packages

I have installed iptables-persistent, I have `ran dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent`, and it does save the rules in `/etc/iptables`

I have the following in the folder
`rules.v4  rules.v6`

On a reboot it will not load my rules.  IF I do this below, it works just fine!  IT will just not do this for me on reboot.

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

I have tried following many leads online, starting from these.

[Why do iptables rules disappear when restarting my Debian system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52376/why-do-iptables-rules-disappear-when-restarting-my-debian-system)

[Why isn't the Iptables persistent service saving my changes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125833/why-isnt-the-iptables-persistent-service-saving-my-changes)

I don't know what I am doing wrong.  I do have fail2ban installed and working.  I can't see this conflicting, but on boot they both would be working with iptables...

Are there ways to view the iptables logs?  Does it log to journalctl?  I cannot find any msges that can give me an idea why it is not working.

These rules gotta load on boot.   Someone did mention to load this in `/etc/rc.local`, which I am unfamiliar with, that file is not there on Debian, and some have explained to just stick with iptables-persistent, which I would tend to agree with.

[Why do iptables rules disappear when restarting my Debian system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52376/why-do-iptables-rules-disappear-when-restarting-my-debian-system#answer-52378)

Any help is appreciated, or logs to iptables if any.

This is my boot logs when I try a reboot `journalctl -f -unetfilter-persistent`

```
Jan 02 15:09:06 domain.ca netfilter-persistent[720]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
Jan 02 15:09:06 domain.ca systemd[1]: Started netfilter persistent configuration.
Jan 02 15:09:50 domain.ca systemd[1]: Stopping netfilter persistent configuration...
Jan 02 15:09:50 domain.ca netfilter-persistent[1434]: Automatic flush disabled; use '/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent flush'
Jan 02 15:09:50 domain.ca systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Succeeded.
Jan 02 15:09:50 domain.ca systemd[1]: Stopped netfilter persistent configuration.
Jan 02 15:09:50 domain.ca systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...
Jan 02 15:09:50 domain.ca netfilter-persistent[1436]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
Jan 02 15:09:50 domain.ca netfilter-persistent[1436]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
Jan 02 15:09:50 domain.ca systemd[1]: Started netfilter persistent configuration.
```

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but I would suggest you to migrate to `nftables` as `iptables` is deprecated, less and less maintained and absent from recent Linux distributions by default. Also, nftables has a built-in systemd `nftables.service` for creating your ruleset (from `/etc/nftables.conf`) automatically during boot.

Comment: @Totor In Debian 10 and later, the `iptables` package contains two versions of `iptables` command: `iptables-legacy` actually uses the iptables kernel components, but the default `iptables-nft` actually uses nftables although the command syntax is identical to iptables. What you get with just `iptables` is switchable with `sudo update-alternatives --config iptables` - but at least Debian 11 and I think 10 too will default to the nftables version.

Comment: @telcoM Sure. Still, this is a transition mechanism for a legacy tool. It could be used to convert a ruleset to `nft` though (using `nft list ruleset` to dump the nftables config once your firewall is configured as you like). Then, use the default mechanism (systemd `nftables.service`) to start it at boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.  After all this time to spend on this.  The only I got it working was to set the restore in rc.local with a `sleep 1`.  There is something on this machine that is taking time to load, as in the network or something.

I have tried editing the daemon in persistent to load later after other components from a thread I read.  Nothing worked.

Finally, on Debian, you can enable rc.local `systemctl enable rc.local`, once this services started, I went into its file `vim /etc/rc.local` and added the following

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel
sleep 1
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# bash /root/restore.sh
exit 0
```

After a reboot, all my rules are up.  I think the better solution is as others have mentioned to move to another firewall since iptables will be deprecated.  But I have complicated rules and no time.

Answer (score 0):

Iptables interacts with Linux netfilter in the background:

Install iptables-persistent packages

```
$ sudo iptables-persistent -y
```

Start and enable iptables-persistent service

```
$ sudo systemctl enable --now netfilter-persistent.service
```

To save the netfilter/iptables rules:

```
$ sudo netfilter-persistent save
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your comment.  But I've tried all these, as per the links I've posted.  None of them work.  If I do `systemctl restart netfilter-persistent` however, it works.  So basically the service is loading too fast from what I can understand.  I just can't figure out how to fix

Comment: @gstlouis, obviously this has been a while, but I've just been debugging a similar problem and it was caused by my having a hostname in the rules file instead of an ip address. I guess the rules are being applied before the dns server comes up? Chaging to an ip address solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Dan
Thanks for the comment.  So to make sure I understand, if I go into /etc/iptables/rules.v4 which is what iptables will fetch to load when booting I should be looking for any DNS naming instead of ip?  Because if I do a vim /etc/iptables/rules.v4 I do not see any dns names in my rules.

Comment: @gstlouis yes, using domains instead of ips was the cause for me